# no new line in terminal after setting up cakephp

Tags: php, macos, cakephp, terminal

I attempted to set up vi .profile for baking in cakephp but now when I open terminal (mac OSX) I get the following error

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_gd2.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_gd2.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

I can't type in any commands into terminal and pressing enter just drops the line down. The "title" of terminal says PHP 5.3.1, so I'm not sure if it somehow left the standard user mode (whatever that's called). I've restarted my computer and terminal opens up with this same message.

Is there some kind of command I can enter in the menus to revert out of this? Can someone please help me get terminal back to "normal."

edit - I went to shell->new command and typed in su root; to log in. This works, however, when I open up a new terminal window I still get the same php error and I can't figure out how to log in normally when terminal opens.

Comment: What's the question. To get it back to normal just edit out your .profile changes. If you want help getting your profile set up correctly you'll need to post the contents of the file

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say what is the default settings for .profile? I wasn't thinking and forgot to write it down

Comment: Hmm, nevermind. It seems to be working now. I did absolutely nothing since I last posted.

Comment: You can always CONTROL+C if the command is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

The `~/.profile` by defauilt is empty on OSX (at least on my machine). So just commenting everything out or just removing the pieces you added for the cakePHP will clear the parts that are messing up your new shells.